# php curl fetching images from webpage

Tags: php, html, curl

I am interested in trying with web scraping . but i'm throwing with the error if i use the below code 
like ( ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function innertext() on a non-object )

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

set_time_limit(300); 


$url = "http://www.flickr.com/photos/terriek/galleries/72157622371738280/"; 

echo $url;
$ch = curl_init(); 

echo $ch;

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, TRUE);    
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);    
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

//echo $result;

curl_close($ch);


$html = new simple_html_dom();

echo $html;

$html->load($result);

$exts = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

foreach($html->find('img') as $element) // error with this line 

    $path_parts = pathinfo($element->src);

    // if condition 

        $ch = curl_init($element->src);


        $fp = fopen("imgs/".$path_parts['basename'], "wb");


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);


        echo curl_exec($ch);


        curl_close($ch);

        fclose($fp);
```

Comment: The code looks fine at the first glance, are you sure the first curl call returns what you expect?

Comment: no it is not returning any value as i even tried with it

Comment: Yeah, the url returns an empty string for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're missing the full URL when you curl inside your loop.

try:

```
echo $element->src;
```

in your loop and make sure it's giving the full URL and if it is giving a relative URL, prepend your $url to it before curling.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the main url - when you open it in the browser, you'll see it redirects to the secure protocol, so updating it to `https` should make your code work:

```
$url = "https://www.flickr.com/photos/terriek/galleries/72157622371738280/";
```